# How to compare array and object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, compare

I have two json array and object 
I would like to compare two json and push another object

```
obj1 = ["user1", "user2"]
obj2 = [
  {
    "userName": "user1", 
    "id": "14" 
  },
  {
    "userName": "user2",
    "id": "9",
  },
  {
    "userName": "user3",
    "id": "3",
  },
  {
    "userName": "user4",
    "id": "1",
  }
]
```

I would like to get the result as below

```
[
  {
    "userName": "user1",
    "id": "14"
  },
  {
    "userName": "user2",
    "id": "9",
  }
]
```

After, I tried to compare two arrays and get a result what I need.

```
var obj1 = ["user1","user2"]
var obj2 = [
  {
    "userName": "user1",
    "id": "14"
  },
  {
    "userName": "user2",
    "id": "9",
  },
  {
    "userName": "user3",
    "id": "3",
  },
  {
    "userName": "user4",
    "id": "1",
  }
]

var objArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
if (obj1[i] === obj2.userName) {
  objArray.push(obj2[i]);
}
return objArray;
```

Please help me to solve the issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could filter by checking the name with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var array1 = ["user1", "user2"],
    array2 = [{ userName: "user1", id: "14" }, { userName: "user2", id: "9", }, { userName: "user3", id: "3", }, { userName: "user4", id: "1", }],
    result = array2.filter(({ userName }) => array1.includes(userName));
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops:

- iterate through `obj1[i]`, and for each index of `obj1`...

  - iterate through `obj2[]` and test each object to see whether the `username` property's value equals that of `obj[i]`.

```js
 var obj1 =  ["user1","user2"]
 var obj2 = [
  {  
    "userName": "user1", 
   "id": "14" 
  },
 {

   "userName": "user2",  
    "id": "9",    
 },
 {

    "userName": "user3",    
    "id": "3",
  },
{

    "userName": "user4",    
   "id": "1",
 }] 

function myFunction(){
  var objArray = [];
  for (var i=0; i < obj1.length; i++) {
    for (var userIndex=0; userIndex < obj2.length; userIndex++){
      if (obj1[i] === obj2[userIndex].userName){
       objArray.push( obj2[userIndex] );
      }
    }
  }
  return objArray;
};

console.log(myFunction());
```